# Bit - bit tag fails with typescript error

Tags: reactjs, deployment, bit, circleci

I develop to a component lib, that use bit: https://bit.dev/

When i update components props that relay on each other, i get this error in the circle-ci (but no localy). this error is when circle-ci run `bit tag`

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TagsProps'

on this instance i added `ref` with forwardRef to `<Tags/>` which `<Dropdown/>` is it's parent, and pass it ref from `<Dropdown />`

what am i missing?

**Tags component**

```
export const Tags = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, TagsProps>(
  (
    {
      values,
      onRemoveTag,
      onClickTag,
      tagClassName,
      onMouseEnterTag,
      onMouseLeaveTag,
      id,
      ['data-testid']: dataTestId,
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    return (
      <StyledTags data-testid={dataTestId} ref={ref} id={id}>
        {values.map((value, index) => {
```

**Using Tags**

```
<Tags
            data-testid={generateTestId('-tags')}
            ref={tagsRef}
            values={selectionsToShow as string[]}
            onRemoveTag={onRemoveTag}
            onClickTag={onRemoveTag}
          />
          {hiddenTags}
        </StyledTagsContainer>
```

Comment: You need to add the code, how you're declaring and forwarding the ref

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos added the code.

Comment: Please run ```bit env``` and copy the output